# How do I get nested filtered list with map and filter?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I'm pretty newbie in Java and learning Java8 with stream. 
And I want to get list filtered.
I need filtered list with nestedlist is "22".
But I am struggling make this. Is anybody save me?

I put some simple code below.
I tried this like below but It is now working.

```
List<Custom> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.stream().map(
  x -> x.getNestedList.stream().filter(
       y->y.getValue.equals("22")
  )
)


Before
[
  {
   "a":"1",
   "nestedlist": [ {"11"},
                   {"22"},
                   {"33"} ]
  },
  {
   "a":"2",
   "nestedlist": [ {"22"}, 
                   {"44"} ]
  },
  {  
   "a":"3",
   "nestedlist": [ {"11"}, 
                   {"33"} ]
  },
  {
   "a":"4",
   "nestedlist": [ {"b":"11"} ]
  }
]



After 
(Nestedlist has filtered by "22", but parent list still has whole element)
[
  {
   "a":"1",
   "nestedlist": [ {"22"}]
  },
  {
   "a":"2",
   "nestedlist": [ {"22"} ]
  },
  {  
   "a":"3",
   "nestedlist": [  ]
  },
  {
   "a":"4",
   "nestedlist": [  ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the values in your original data structure, or build and return a copy that has been filtered?

Comment: Please clarify what you want your output to look like.

Comment: It does not matter. New list will be better in ma case

Comment: @Randy can you share the definition of Custom class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something that should be close to a solution but without the definition of nestedList, it's only a draft. You will have to adapt it to your code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
   static class Custom<T>{
       String a;
       List<T> nestedList;

       public Custom(String a, List<T> nestedList) {
           this.a = a;
           this.nestedList = nestedList;
       }

       public Custom(String a, T... nestedList) {
           this.a = a;
           this.nestedList = Arrays.asList(nestedList);
       }

       public String getA() {
           return a;
       }

       public void setA(String a) {
           this.a = a;
       }

       public List<T> getNestedList() {
           return nestedList;
       }

       public void setNestedList(List<T> nestedList) {
           this.nestedList = nestedList;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Custom{" +
                   "a='" + a + '\'' +
                   ", nestedList=" + nestedList +
                   '}' +
                   '\n';
       }
   }



   public static void main(String... args){
       List<Custom> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add(new Custom<String>("1", "11", "22", "33"));
       list.add(new Custom<String>("2", "22", "44"));
       list.add(new Custom<String>("3", "11", "33"));

       List result = list.stream().map(
               x -> new Custom(x.getA(), x.getNestedList().stream().filter(y -> y.equals("22")).collect(Collectors.toList()))
       ).collect(Collectors.toList());

       System.out.println("input: "+list);
       System.out.println("result: "+result);
    }


}
```

Which gives as output

```
input: [Custom{a='1', nestedList=[11, 22, 33]}
, Custom{a='2', nestedList=[22, 44]}
, Custom{a='3', nestedList=[11, 33]}
]
result: [Custom{a='1', nestedList=[[22]]}
, Custom{a='2', nestedList=[[22]]}
, Custom{a='3', nestedList=[[]]}
]
```

The main issue with your code (if I understood what you were trying to do correctly, which I'm absolutely not sure) is that you are mapping the initial `Custom` object to a `Stream` of the content of the nestedList. What you have to do, is map a `Custom` to a new updated `Custom` (what I did) or update the existing `Custom`  (and so the existing list) for which you need a `forEach()` or a basic loop instead of the `map()`